# How can i pre-install plugins in jenkins on Windows docker?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, dockerfile

I am working on Windows docker, trying to install plugins into my jenkins using docker scripts and make it ready for startup.

On linux docker i used to install plugins like this

RUN /usr/local/bin/plugins.sh /var/jenkins_home/plugins.txt

is there any similar way in Windows docker?

Comment: Do you want to have a jenkins ready to work or do you want to keep versioning the configuration?

Comment: yes, I want to keep the jenkins ready to work.

Answer (score 1):

By "Windows docker" I assume you meant Windows containers.  There are two kinds of Docker plugin.  V1 plugin is a binary application that enhances the capability of Docker engine.  V2 is a containerized version of that.  In both cases, the plugin must be written and compiled for each platform, and Windows Engine currently does not support V2 plugins (as of Dec. 2017).

So your Linux Jenkins plugin will not run on Windows until it is recompiled for Windows platform by its author.  This is a good question to ask Jenkins community or maybe CloudBees team. Hope this service as a pointer.